# Disable Sidepanel - Framework7

Tags: html-framework-7

so i'm making a hybrid mobile app using framework7. I have a little problem though. Ok so, I have a sidepanel that automatically disables when the user opens the app. When the user logs in and gets redirected to the main view the sidepanel gets enabled. So far I've got that working. I'm having trouble disabling the sidepanel when the user logs out. I've read through some question on the Internet and tried a couple of things.

First I've tried using `myApp.allowPanelOpen = false;` when the user logs out.

```
//Log out
$(document).on("click", '.logout', function(){
    myApp.allowPanelOpen = false;
    myApp.closePanel();

    window.localStorage.clear();
    mainView.router.loadPage({url:'index.html', ignoreCache:true, reload:true });
});
```

This doesn't work at all, after I'm redirected to the index page I can still open the sidepanel by swiping right.

Secondly I've tried combining `myApp.allowPanelOpen = false;` and the `myApp.params.swipePanel = false;`

```
//Log out
$(document).on("click", '.logout', function(){
    myApp.allowPanelOpen  = false;
    myApp.params.swipePanel = false;
    myApp.closePanel();

    window.localStorage.clear();
    mainView.router.loadPage({url:'index.html', ignoreCache:true, reload:true });
});
```

This also doesn't work because I can't open the panel at all even after I set `myApp.allowPanelOpen = true;` and `myApp.params.swipePanel= true;` after the user logs in.

Anyone know how I can go about this? Any help is greatly appreciated, this is the code I'm currently running:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  // Init App
  var myApp = new Framework7({
    modalTitle: 'La Cava Express',
    material: true,
    pushState : true,
    swipePanel: "left"
  });

  //Disable sidepanel by default when app started (this is working)
  myApp.allowPanelOpen = false;

  // Define Dom7
  var $$ = Dom7;

  // Init View
  var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {});

  //Main screen after the user logs in
  myApp.onPageInit('promo-catalog', function (page) {
    //Enable sidepanel when user starts this page
    myApp.allowPanelOpen = true;

  });

  //Log out
  $(document).on("click", '.logout', function(){
    myApp.allowPanelOpen = false;
    myApp.closePanel();

    window.localStorage.clear();
    mainView.router.loadPage({url:'index.html', ignoreCache:true, reload:true });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I got it working. Found this at a blog post. I ended up using the `myApp.params.swipePanel= false;` parameter. I used this parameter on every page I wanted to disable the panel. Whenever I want to enable it on a certain page i used the `myApp.params.swipePanel= 'left';`.

```
//Log in screen
myApp.onPageInit('login', function (page) {
  //Disable sidepanel when user starts this page
  myApp.params.swipePanel = false;

});

//Main screen after the user logs in
myApp.onPageInit('promo-catalog', function (page) {
   //Enable sidepanel when user starts this page
   myApp.params.swipePanel = 'left';

});
```

Answer (score 0):

hide panel only for particular page else show panel code   **Note**   page name is not your file name it's in the file itself data-page="yourpage"

```
  var page = e.detail.page;
  console.log(page.name);
  if(page.name=="services") {

    myApp.params.swipePanel = false;

 }    else 
   {  
       myApp.params.swipePanel='left';
  }
```